# How do you format the table column headings in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, tablecolumn

The following code displays a swift table with all of the correct data.  But, I am unable to figure out how to format the table column headings (such as Index Funds and Shares).  I would like to change the font size and center the text.  Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
struct SummaryTable: View {
    private var localArray: [TradingDayPrices]
    init(passedInArray: [TradingDayPrices]) {
        self.localArray = passedInArray
    }
    var body: some View {
        let funds: [Fund] = GetSummaryTable(localArray: localArray)
        Table(funds) {
            TableColumn("Index Fund") { value in
                Text(value.name)
                    .padding(.vertical, 2)
            }
            .width(90)
            TableColumn("Shares") { value in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(value.shares)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .width(90)
            TableColumn("Share Price") { value in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(value.sharePrice)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .width(90)
            TableColumn("Total") { value in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(value.total)
                }
            }
            .width(110)
            TableColumn("One Year Gain") { value in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(value.percentChange)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .width(90)
        } // end table
        .tableStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 185)
        .padding([.top], 30)
        .padding([.bottom], 700)
    }
}
```

Comment: with `Table` you cannot change the column headers (as of now)

Comment: What's so strange about it is that Table includes a Label type, and explicitly says it generates a Text from your Strings. So adding Text-modifiers should be very straight-forward. You should just pass a Text directly into the `init` (like you can for Button). But it doesn't seem possible. You could attach Text-modifiers to the whole Table, and I would expect them to apply to the column labels, but I don't see any way to limit those modifiers to the column labels. (Every time I try to use Table, it turns out it's not flexible enough. I always have to build it out of stacks.)

Comment: @RobNapier I agree. Its very basic right now ...